# Display Recurring Pattern in List

Tags: list-view

In my list view of event, many of which are recurring, I want to display the recurrence pattern, not just a symbol/image to say whether it is or isn't recurring. In the item itself, Recurrence is just a check box which then allows more specific options (day of week etc) but in standard view item mode, it displays a pattern description, which is a logical combination of all the options selected. I want this pattern description to appear in my list view (and then allow me to include it in an excel export).

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible although convoluted and require you to also use a SPD workflow...

Firstly, the recurrence of an item is stored in a Hidden Multi Line column, which is ludicrous because you cannot calculated columns from it. So you will have to create a new column called 'My Recurrence Data' for example set as a Single Line of Text.

Create a SPD Workflow that executes on both Create and Change, Call it 'Update My Recurrence  Data' for example and have one statement in it which would be

Set [My Recurrence Data] to [RecurrenceData]

Now that you have that sorted out you can obtain the Recurrence Type from the new column...

The My Recurrence Data will get populated with XML every time you add or change an item, the XML looks like this:

```
<recurrence><rule><firstDayOfWeek>mo</firstDayOfWeek><repeat><monthlyByDay th="TRUE" weekdayOfMonth="third" monthFrequency="5" /></repeat><repeatForever>FALSE</repeatForever></rule></recurrence>
```

Create another column called Recurrence Type which is a calculated Single Line of text, the formula for extracting the recurrence type of the item would be:

```
=MID([My Recurrence Data],(SEARCH("<",[My Recurrence Data],SEARCH("<repeat><",[My Recurrence Data])+1)+1),((SEARCH(" ",[My Recurrence Data],SEARCH("<repeat><",[My Recurrence Data])+1)+1)-(SEARCH("<",[My Recurrence Data],SEARCH("<repeat><",[My Recurrence Data])+1)+1))-1)
```

This will then calculate the recurrence type, in the above XML it would return monthlyByDay.